# Is $rootScope a good idea for Toast Notifications?

Tags: angularjs, rest, service

I'm planning out my app and running across a problem with development principals in Angular.  I've got an app that communicates to an API backend and will return messages based on REST API principles.

Here's a snippet of an example service I'm using:

```
this.POST = function(url, data) {
        console.log(data);
        $http({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            headers: headers
        }).
        success(function(data) {
            $rootScope.toasted = data;
        }).
        error(function() {
            $rootScope.toasted = 'There was an API communication error.';
        });
    };
```

Right now, a div at the top of my screen (The Toast Notification itself) will update based on these success or errors states for each API function (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).  I'm using `$rootScope` to do it, but I have a feeling there's a much safer and better way to do this.

Should I stick with `$rootScope` so that I can always updated a toast notification anywhere in my app?  Or should I not cloud `$rootScope` at all and somehow use a controller or other Service to perform this function?

Comment: That depends on how complex your notifications are going to get. If you need to abstract things out, then you could probably move things to a controller or service, but if you are just displaying a message, then you are fine with $rootScope. You might just want to give it a more complex name than 'toasted' since all child scopes will share the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to try to think of all the pieces of your applications as isolated places that associate with others if they so choose.

The problem with using `$rootScope` is that it forces those properties onto children scopes that may not care about it. You're sharing the data with the scopes that you want to have it, but you're also sharing it with scopes that don't need it. Using `$rootScope` is comparable to declaring global variables and the same principles apply.

Sharing data is usually done via a service that any concerned component can opt-in to by injecting the service. Broadcasting or emitting an event may also be appropriate depending on the circumstance.

It sounds to me like there are three components involved:

- The data (object or array)
- The service that manipulates the data
- The controller that binds the data to the UI

The data may be in its own service or in the same service that manipulates the data. I can't say which would be cleanest without seeing the specifics. When the service has performed an operation, it could `$broadcast` an event on `$rootScope` which the controller could opt-in to via `$scope.$on`, and it could access the data from the event, or through the data service.